# RSA simple exercise

Tags: modular-arithmetic

An exercise asks me to encrypt with RSA a message m=10. The public key e=11 and the private key d=11. The modulo is 60.

So i tried first to cipher this way:
C=10^11 mod 60=40

So 40 is my ciphertext.

Then the exercise asks me to decrypt it.

So I did M=40^11 mod 60

But the result is 40 again when it should be 10.

How is it possible? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @A Typically, it is assumed that the modulus (in this case 60) and the message $m$ are relatively prime. Because this is not the case and because the modulus is not square-free, the usual algorithm doesn’t work correctly.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: No, it is not necessary that $n$ and $m$ are co-prime. RSA works regardless. The problem here is that $60$ is not the modulus $-$ see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

$60$ is not the modulus $-$ it can't be, because it is not a product of two primes.

We see that the product of the public key and the private key is $121$, so each is the inverse of the other modulo $60$; this suggests that $60$ is $\varphi(n)$, where $n$ is the modulus.

To find the modulus $n=pq$, look for primes $p$ and $q$ such that $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)=60$. Then it all works nicely $-$ you should find that $(10^{11})^{11}\equiv 10\bmod n$.

Comment: Yes you were right, it was 77. Thank you!